# Can I set multiple headers with Siege?

Tags: http-headers, load-testing, siege

I want to use siege to target a number of URLs on my app, each with different headers. I can set headers for one request

```
siege -u http://localhost/xyz -d1 -r1000 -c25 --header="Token: f2840fc1"
```

(this appears to be [undocumented](http://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/))

I can specify a list of URLs in the URL file, with custom headers for each URL. But I can't see a way in the docs.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I think the answer was no.

Comment: while there is no way to set multiple headers for different URLs, you can set multiple headers for all URLs by saying siege --header="My1:Value1" --header="My2:Value2" -f urls.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest using two concurrent calls to `siege`. Write a URL file that uses Header-A, and another for Header-B.

For my API testing, I've got a `get_urls.txt` file and `post_json_urls.txt` file, which I call on two instances of Siege at once. This way one gets called with `Content-Type: text/json` and the other doesn't. Short of rewriting the [Siege url parser](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/blob/accea618b890c43f65197a4960fff6fb24e4df56/src/url.c#L614), this is the only way I know to do it.

For example:

```
siege -f get_urls.txt & siege -H 'Content-Type: text/json' -f post_json_urls.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful advice.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see from the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/siege.1.html) and reading around I think you are right. The only way to specify headers is on the command line using the `-H --header` options not in the URL file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example `siege --concurrent=5 --reps=100 --header='sdk:3.0, config:3.0,zid:0' 'https://google.com/api/REGME POST uid=a8qn&aid=43ZK0'`